# Insertion from View to multiple models in MVC using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

As a beginner in to MVC using EF, I am stuck with a problem is that,  I wanted to input data from View to two models. This 2 models represents one parent and one child table in the .edmx.

The first problem is, when user inputs, I need to split one inputted field data in to two and bind each part in to two properties of model.

Next problem is, how can I bind values of html form components in to two models.

I could see many solutions but its all confusing me as a beginner. Could you please suggest me a better approach to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you can easily use the Entity framework's Feature just make sure your tables have the relationship between them .

In Your EF  when u have a foreign key constraint then you can see a class in your model called virtual class i have all your relational class data just u have to get the Id n pass & you can access that easily.

Or else you can create a View Model in that you can Use two or more models at the same time .

Row example is like this

```
return new
{
    Details= new
    {
        PId = EF_parent.Id,
        PName = EF_parent.Name,
        CId = EF_child.Id, 
        CName = EF_child.Name
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, could you please tell me how to bind splitted data ? eg: one table in the  EF has date_from and date_to properties, but there is only one html form text box which accept it as '2017-05-12'-'2017-06-11'. How can i split this and bind it to two properties in the EF table?

Comment: You can get the value of the text box and split it into two value and sotre into a variable thn pass it to the model